# Derivative of a vector with scalar product in denominator

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I'm struggling with a partial derivative of the following form:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} \frac{\vec{x}}{\vec{e}_3^T\,\vec{x}},
\end{equation}
where $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\vec{e}_3 = (0, 0, 1)^\top$ is the third Euclidean basis vector. Does anyone know the derivative of this?